# Python: determining location in nested tuple

Tags: python, recursion, tuples, depth

I'm wondering if you can help.

I have a tuple that looks like

```
(1,2,(3,4,(5,(6,4),2),1,2))
```

I want to find all numbers and their locations.
Forexample, I want all integers except the first in a tuple. I have written a recursive script to do this,

```
a=[]
def getNumbers(t):
    for i,item in enumerate(t):
        if type(item) is int:
            if i > 0:
                a.append(item)
        else:
            getNumbers(item)
```

but I cannot seem to determine their depth in the overall tuple. Can you help?

Comment: *I have written a recursive script to do this, but I cannot seem to determine their depth in the overall tuple.* Please do share that script, it is *far easier* to help you with code already written.

Comment: First `flatten` this tuple to a 1D tuple and then simply use `collections.Counter` to get the desired output.

Comment: You need to count the depth as you call the recursive function, like `getNumbers(t, depth)` and then when you call it, call like `getNumbers(item, depth+1)`

Comment: absolutely never thought to increment there. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to count the depth as you call the recursive function, when you make the initial call pass a depth of zero, then `depth + 1` on each recursive call.

```
data = (1,2,(3,4,(5,(6,4),2),1,2)) a=[]

def getNumbers(t, depth):
    for i,item in enumerate(t):
        if type(item) is int:
            if i > 0:
                a.append(item)
        else:
            getNumbers(item, depth + 1)

# call passing initial depth of 0.
getNumbers(data, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd structure this a little differently. Here's a solution that gives you a dictionary mapping the items you are looking for to (nesting-level, index) tuples and that does not rely on an external container:

```
def findall(tup, which, res=None, nest=0):
    'tup: nested tuple, which: set of items to find'
    if res is None:
        res = {}
    for index, item in enumerate(tup):
        if isinstance(item, tuple):
            findall(item, which, res, nest+1)
        elif item in which:
            res.setdefault(item, []).append((nest, index))
    return res

print(findall((1,2,(3,4,(5,(6,4),2),1,2)), {3,4}))
```

Output: `{3: [(1, 0)], 4: [(1, 1), (3, 1)]}`

Reads:
 3 is at nesting level 1 at index 0. 
4 is at nesting level 1 at index 1.
4 is at nesting level 3 at index 1.

Comment: Agreed, this is a better implementation.